# Three-tier Wordpress Query (Parent Taxonomy, Child Taxonomy, Posts within Child Taxonomy)

Tags: custom-post-type, taxonomy, wordpress

Hopefully someone can help me with this, I'm struggling to wrap my head around it!

The website I'm working on has a meetings and minutes section that I'm trying to put together, I've got a custom post type with a taxonomy, and I'm trying to make a page template that lays this out like so...

PARENT CATEGORY (YEAR)

CHILD CATEGORY (MONTHS)

post from child category (INDIVIDUAL MEETINGS)

CHILD CATEGORY (MONTHS)

post from child category (INDIVIDUAL MEETINGS)

CHILD CATEGORY (MONTHS)

post from child category (INDIVIDUAL MEETINGS)

(and then repeats, loading in the next year and it's months, meetings and so on)

Any ideas how I could achieve this, I've tried a load of different ways on other sites but nothing seems to fit this specifically. I've mostly been playing about to see if anything fits.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to understand how you would like to display, but following code will give you direction,

```html
$args = array('hide_empty' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'parent' => 0);
$parentTerms = get_terms("taxonomy-type", $args);

foreach($hiterms as $key => $parentTerm) {  
    $args2 = array('hide_empty' => false,  'parent' => $parentTerm->term_id);
    $childTerms = get_terms("taxonomy-type", $args2);
    if($childTerms) {
            $argsForPost = array(
                'post_type' => 'postType',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-type',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $childTerms,
                        'operator' => 'AND'
                    )
                )
            );
            $myPosts = get_posts( $argsForPost );
    }
}
```